# Connecting class function to a button.(QT C++)

Tags: c++, qt, function, class

I am curious how to connect a function in a class to a button in QT. I am trying to use this one:

```
connect(ui->m_but,SIGNAL(clicked()),&Downloader,SLOT(DoDownload()));
```

I have a class `Downloader`. A button name `m_but`. Function `DoDownload` to call.

Also tried to make a slot function in my class which calls `DoDownload`. But no result.

Comment: You don't connect signals to a class, but rather to an object.  So if you have an object of type Downloader, specify a pointer to that object as your third argument to connect(), rather than the name of the Downloader class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a class Downloader.

But do you have an instance of it? You do need to instantiate the class in order to connect to it.

You should have something like this in your class body:

```
Downloader downloader;
```

Then `connect(ui->m_but, SIGNAL(clicked()), &downloader, SLOT(DoDownload()));` should work.

In the case `Downloader` is a "static class", that is it has no non-static members, then it can be used without creating an instance of it. In that case, you'd have to use the new connection syntax, available in Qt 5:

```
connect(ui->m_but, &QPushButton::clicked, Downloader::DoDownload);
```